# DeleteByQuery ElasticSearch Golang error elastic: Error 404 (Not Found)

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I'm trying to delete the documents from my Index with specific productIDs.

Here's the sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    elastic "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v3"
)

func main() {

    client, err := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetSniff(false), elastic.SetURL("http://localhost:9200"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot create ES client:", err)
    }
    boolQuery := elastic.NewBoolQuery().Must(elastic.NewTermQuery("productId", "1503368"))

    searchQuery := client.Search().Query(boolQuery).
        Index("magento1").Type("catalog")
    result, err := searchQuery.Do()
    for _, hit := range result.Hits.Hits {
        var data bson.M
        _ = json.Unmarshal(*hit.Source, &data)
        fmt.Println("SEARCH RESPONSE\n", data)
    }

    result2, err2 := elastic.NewDeleteByQueryService(client).
        Index("magento1").
        Type("catalog").
        Query(boolQuery).
        Do()
    fmt.Println("DELETE RESPONSE 2: \n", result2, err2)

}
```

The SearchQuery gives the correct response and returns me the document with the provided productId (I DID THIS JUST TO VERIFY IF THE DOCUMENT EXISTS OR NOT).

Now the deletion, I don't know what on earth is wrong with the code or if there's anything missing in the API or something extra has to be added (matchAll etc) but this deleteQuery is just not deleting the Index and is always giving me the response:

```
error elastic: Error 404 (Not Found)
```

I've searched all the blogs/docs/official library's GitHub [tests](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/release-branch.v5/delete_by_query.go) cases etc but none resolved my problem. Although I've come to a resolution to Scan/Scroll and Bulk delete still wonder why this is not working if it's in the official documentation.

Here's the mapping:

```
"productId": bson.M{"type": "string", "store": true, "index": "not_analyzed"},
```

ES VERSION:
`5.3.1`

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an error in the ES logs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that your using `elastic.v3` which [targets ES 2.x](https://github.com/olivere/elastic#elastic-30).

Since you're using ES 5.3.1, you need to use [`elastic.v5`](https://github.com/olivere/elastic#elastic-50), so simply replace this line

```
elastic "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v3"
```

by

```
elastic "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5"
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Well i always thought elastic.v3 is for ES 5.3.1 somehow thus never bothered to look. I still couldn't confirm if switching to elastic.v5 would resolve because i can't upgrade my golang to 1.7 to run elastic.v5 (I have golang 1.5.1). Alhough can't test it, I believe this is the right answer. Accepting. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, don't hesitate to come back here if needed.